# Both virtual hosts go to default

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I'm trying to add a virtual host to xampp server but it seems I'm missing something because the second site does not show up, localhost is displayed instead. I don't know what is wrong with these settings:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/site1/public"
    ServerName site1
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/site1/public">
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         Options all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I added the virtual host to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost   site1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try just adding

```
127.0.0.1 site1.local
```

to your hosts file (on windows C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)

save file and make sure to restart xampp from the control panel

Comment: Thanks anyway. I've already tried that and from what I gathered from the web, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

In your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost localhost>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost site1>
    DocumentRoot "c:\xampp\htdocs\site1\public"
    ServerName site1
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 site1
```

**What I've done here:**

- Instead of using `*:80`, I'm using the name of the host. This gives it a more direct matching approach.
- I've exchanged all forward slashed with backslashes. This doesn't really make a difference, but Windows uses backslashes - this is just a rule of thumb.
- I have removed `NameVirtualHost` as, to my current knowledge, it does not make any difference, and thus depreciated. Future versions may recogise it as an unknown key.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just use the solution from Mike and do not forget to uncomment line

```
#Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

within your httpd.conf file